# get id, start and end point in a user selection

Tags: javascript, html

I want to get id, start and end point of an user selection, for example I have a series of `<p>` with an id:

```
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <p id="1"> first paragraph </p>
    <p id="2"> second paragraph </p>
    <p id="3"> third paragraph </p>
    <p id="4"> fourth paragraph </p>
    <input type="button" onclick="get()"></input>
  </body>
</html>
```

I use `window.getSelection()` to get the user selection but I don't know how to continue.

Comment: Looks like you need a multiline select for what you're doing.

Comment: BTW - IDs cannot start with numbers.

Comment: Id's aren't allowed to start with numbers.

Comment: I use numbers for the example only, sorry!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var allP = document.getElementsByTagName("p");
for (var i = 0;i < allP.length;i++) {
    (function(num) {
        allP[i].click(function() {
            alert(num);
        })
    })(i);
}
```

I hope it can Inspire you~